# CoffeeScript keeps triggering Error when I'm getting a 200 response back?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm trying to do a `remote: true` form and I have it all setup, and when I click the submit button, the error action triggers every time. This is how my CoffeeScript is setup:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_report").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#new_report").append "<p>SUCCESS</p>"
  ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#new_report").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

And my Reports_Controller

```
  def create
    @report = Report.new(params[:report])

    respond_to do |format|
    if @report.save
    format.json { render json: "Created", :status => :created }
     else
    format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
     end
```

And my form:

```
    <%= form_for(@report, remote: true ) do |t| %>
<p id="reportalert"></p>
    <%= t.text_field  :plant_site,    placeholder: "Plant Site" %>

    <%= t.text_field  :route_number,  placeholder: "Route Number" %>

    <%= t.text_field  :driver_name,   placeholder: "Driver name if available" %>

    <%= t.date_select :date_recorded, html: { class: "input-block-level" } %>

    <%= t.text_field  :action,        placeholder: "Action taken" %>

    <%= t.text_area   :report_body,   placeholder: "What you witnessed",
                                     style: "height: 300px;",
                                     class: "input-block-level" %>

    <%= t.submit     "File Report",  class: "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>

    <% end %>
```

But I check the rails log, and it's nothing but a 200 response, no errors, and the information is submitted to the database, so why is the `ajax:error` triggering? I have also tried replacing the `ajax:error` and `ajax:success` with `ajaxSuccess` and `ajaxError` but then it just doesn't do anything. Any information would be great thanks.

I'm trying to follow: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: edgeguides is for rails version 4, by the way. You have put the rails 3 tag on your question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're not returning a status in the JSON response from the controller.  This is what triggers the ajax:success in jQuery:

```
if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 ) {....}
```

So your respond_to block should look like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @report.save
    format.json { render json: "Created", :status => :created }
  else
    format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: I added `status: :created` to my json, but still, just errors when I'm getting a 201 back